# Google chrome push notification cut the title display

Tags: windows, google-chrome, push-notification

In current (62) version of Google Chrome, push notifiation title is cutted, if it's length between 27 and 38 symbols.
In this case the last word is not diplayed.
If I try to send title like  "The last word of this title not displayed", only "The last word of this title not" is showed.
But if I add some symbols before the last word or add any symbols after (so that the length is greater than 38 characters), the title will display correcly.
Have any Idea for this bug solve?

[It's easy test here](https://tests.peter.sh/notification-generator/#title=The%20last%20word%20of%20this%20title%20not%20displayed;;body=The%20last%20word%20of%20this%20title%20not%20displayed;;dir=1;;actions=3;;action=2).

Comment: same problem here.. no fix yet?

Comment: I'm having this problem too, I'm wondering how the heck so few people ran into this